# patterns and textures with ggplot2 geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

I have a short question regarding **ggplot2**. Is it possible to get testures and patterns when using `geom_area()`?

I've seen the `ggpattern` extension, but it does not seem to work on `geom_area()`, though I might be wrong.

Comment: Hi there, has you considered parameterising your area plot as a polygon and then using the polygon tool from ggpattern? It would typically require just adding 2 vertices to your data at [xmin,0] and [xmax,0].

Comment: Thanks teunbrand. Yeah I thought about this but did not go for it yet. My geom_area is a portion of a probability distribution curve, that is it goes from xmin to xmax but on y it follows the distribution curve. I do not know if this is feasible under polygon + ggpatern()? Thanks again.